# валидация и рекапча modx revo

Tags: javascript, html, cms, modx

всем привет, почему не проходит валидация и проверка рекапчи? нажимаю отправить происходит редирект и все, ни писаьма, ни проверок

вот форма

```
<form role="form" action="[[~31]]" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" >
</div>                                                               
<div class="form-group">
<textarea class="dopinf" rows="5" cols="10" anme="message" placeholder="Дополнительная информация"></textarea>
</div>  
<div class="form-item">
[[!recaptchav2_render]]
[[!+fi.error.recaptchav2_error]]
</div>
<div class="submit-contact"><input type="submit" class="otprav-contact" value="Отправить"></div>
</form>
```

ресурс(31)

```
[[!FormIt?
&hooks=`recaptchav2,email,redirect`
&emailTpl=`ZContactsTpl`
&emailTo=`info@lsweb.ru`
&emailSubject=`Заказ услуги с сайта`
&emailFrom=`maksimdrosdow@outlook.com`
&validate=`name:minLength=^2^,
email:email:required,
message:minLength=^10^,
g-recaptcha-response:required`
&redirectTo=`16`

]]
```

и чанк

Сообщение со страницы «Контакты»Имя:[[+name:default=`Не заполнено`]]

```
Email:[[+email:default=`Не заполнено`]]
Сообщение:[[+message:default=`Не заполнено`]]
```

Comment: Прописано всё правильно. Может в системных настройках неправильно ключи указал, может хук recaptchav2 не отрабатывает, тут только ты сам можешь на своём сайте это проверить.

Comment: та же проблема. Если галочку рекапчи поставить, то письмо отправляется. А вот если не поставить, то страница просто обновляется (в таком случае письмо не приходит)